# How to replicate existing aws-ec2 instances and s3 data on nearest location/endpoints for improved network throughput?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am a remote developer working out of India. My client is based out of North America and has his ec2 servers/s3 data kept in the us-west-2 region.

The number of hops needed to fetch the data is obviously big and thus wastes a lot of my time during testing, as we are dependent on large data coming in from s3.

How can I replicate the existing ec2/s3 system to have an endpoint in India so that my testing performance can be increased?

Comment: It can be easier to run testing software on an ec2 instance in us-west-2 AWS region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can. You just need to setup infrastructure clone and copy all data to India region. There are several BUTs:

- running cost. You (resp. your client) will have to pay for running environment in India. It can be thousands of dollars and maybe it can lead to hiring US-based developer (because your salary + India environment is more expensive than US developers salary.)
- setup cost. Someone from your client must setup this clone corresponding to US environment. This can takes months (depends on how much automation is prepared and how fresh it is). Same for data, it can takes a lot of time to copy data to India
- Synchronization between US and IND. Your copy of infrastructure must be up to date with structure in US, same as testing data. Someone from your client must handle it.
- Law regulation. Maybe there are some data which must be stored in US and cannot be copied to India.

All of those questions must be answered by your client, not by us.